# ADO NET Destination has failed to acquire the connection with the following error message: "Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016

Created a SSIS package, it is running fine when I run it on premise but when i try to execute it from sql server agent it gives me error for login failed for user, I am using SQL authentication to connect to the Azure database which are working fine on premise but erroring out on Job agent

This the Error I am getting:

> Server Execute Package Utility  Version 14.0.1000.169 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft. All rights reserved.    Started:  10:59:46 AM  Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71     Code: 0xC0208452     Source: Data Flow Task ADO NET Destination [2]     Description: ADO NET Destination has failed to acquire the connection {F51F409E-2990-4C40-8DFF-0B078AF481D4} with the following error message: "Login failed for user 'SVCASQLDW'.".  End Error  Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: ADO NET Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC0208452.  End Error  Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2019-06-07 10:59:47.71     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  10:59:46 AM  Finished: 10:59:47 AM  Elapsed:  0.875 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Answer (score 1):

Test in powershell to validate your connection parameters:

```
dbrowne> $constr = "server=xxxxxx.database.windows.net;Database=master;user id=<yourUserName>;password=<yourPassword>"
dbrowne> $con = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection $constr
dbrowne> $con.Open()
```